# Accessing properties of generic types in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Casting the generic type to any works (The type E will be a typescript type, class, or interface) of some entity like Product, Post, Todo, Customer, etc.:

```
function test<E>(o:E):string {
  return (o as any)['property']
}
```

Just wanted to see whether casting to any is generally how this should be handled?

The full context was requested.  Here's is the entire function being implemented:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param entities The entities to search
 * @param exclude Keys to exclude from each entity
 * 
 * @return E[] Array of entities with properties containing the search term.
 */
export function search<E extends WithProperty>(query:string='', entities:E[], exclude:string[]=[]) {
  const { isArray } = Array

  query = query.toLowerCase();

  let keys:string[] = []
  if (entities.length > 0) {
    keys = excludeKeys(entities[0], exclude)
  }

  return entities.filter(function (e:E) {
    return keys.some((key)=>{
      const value = (e as any)[key];
      if (isArray(value)) {
        return value.some(v => {
          return new String(v).toLowerCase().includes(query);
        });
      }
      else if (!isArray(value)) {
        return new String(value).toLowerCase().includes(query);
      }
    })
  });
}
```

```
/**
 * The method can be used to exclude keys from an instance
 * of type `E`.  
 * 
 * We can use this to exclude values when searching an object.
 * 
 * @param entity An instance of type E
 * @param eclude  The keys to exclude
 * 
 */
export function excludeKeys<E>(entity: E, exclude: string[]) {
  const keys: string[] = Object.keys(entity);
  return keys.filter((key) => {
    return exclude.indexOf(key) < 0;
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this really constitute a [mcve]?  What is the use case here?  Do you expect that `o` will always have a `string`-valued property at the key `"property"`?  If so, then `function test<E extends {property: string}>(o: E): string { return o.property }` should work, but so would `function test(o: {property: string}) { return o.property }` with no generics at all.  So I'm confused about what your intent is here.  Good luck!

Comment: This is the use case.  Implementing the search in typescript ATM : https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/filtering-our-javascript-objects-ea73ded722ab

Comment: The object o is just an entity (Customer, Product, etc.) of generic type E ... in other words it will be Typescript class or interface or type instance which IIUC always has a string as the property key.

Comment: I think the `extends` is elegant, but it does not look like it works in this case since the property must be accessed using [].

Comment: Why would the string literal `"property"` need to be accessed using bracket notation?  It sounds like you're saying the actual property might be some random `string`, but you have not shown this in your code.  Please consider editing the code into a true [mcve] which demonstrates the relevant issue.  If `"property"` can change, show it changing.  Show `test()` being called on multiple inputs and what you expect to see.  Etc.

Comment: I minimized the question to the raw parameters needed specifically to obey SO conventions and the spirit of an MVCE.  The example is exactly what I need.  The reason is that, as indicated in the medium article I wrote, each member of the generic object instance is found by first finding the keys of the object and then iterating over the keys.

Comment: Attached the entire search function as requested.

Comment: That attached code has errors unrelated to the question you're asking.  I'd possibly suggest that `keys` should be of type `Array<keyof E>` instead of `string[]`, and then go from there, since if you have a value `o` of type `E` and a value `k` of type `keyof E` then `o[k]` will compile without needing to assert `o` to be `any`.  Without agreement on what constitutes a true [mcve] I can't proceed further, though.  Hopefully you get the answer you seek!

Comment: Thanks!  I really like the keyOf idea!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know  the type constraint has a property named property you can define an interface which defines the property and then use a constraint that tell E extends it. Then you will have access to that property without casting it.

```
interface WithProperty{
  property:string;
}

function test<E extends WithProperty>(o:E):string {
  return o.property;  // or o["property"] is valid access.
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrDACwApQPYAO0YAngN4BQyyB+RUpAXAM5hSgDmA3BQL4UUYAVxAIwwPCGSRWAHgCiyCAA9IIACbM0GHHWIkAfAAo8jeQEoWbTskrUoEMEKhS8AbQBEtQvo8BdLmQAeiCANzgAG2B1ZEQkZmYAOj4BYVFxSWkIVgAmBWNTCyt2EA5bKmQHJxdkdy89BhJ-QJDwqJi47KS+IA)

Edit :
Since you updated your example. There is another way of doing that which is to use keyword `keyof`. Also using this one doesn't require knowledge of the properties. I have modified your example like below :

```
export function search<E>(query:string='', entities:E[], exclude:string[]=[]) {
  const { isArray } = Array
  type EKey = keyof E;
  query = query.toLowerCase();

  let keys : EKey[] = []
  if (entities.length > 0) {
    keys = excludeKeys<E>(entities[0], exclude)
  }

  return entities.filter(function (e:E) {
    return keys.some((key =>{
      const value = e[key];
      if (isArray(value)) {
        return value.some(v => {
          return v.toLowerCase().includes(search);
        });
      }
      else if (!isArray(value)) {
        return new String(value).toLowerCase().includes(query);
      }
    })
  });
 }
```

For the excludeKeys part of the code casting becomes inevitable because of this looong going [discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253).

```
export function excludeKeys<E>(entity: E, exclude: string[]) {
 const keys: string[] = Object.keys(entity);
  return <(keyof E)[]>keys.filter((key) => {
    return exclude.indexOf(key) < 0;
   });
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#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)

Comment: Thanks that's a little more elegant - Unfortunately it has to be `(o as any)['property']` ... in other words the property must be accessed using `[]`

Comment: @Ole it also makes it valid without casting any.

Comment: @Ole added another solution.

Comment: Sweet!!  That looks awesome.  Much cleaner!!

Comment: Hm - I think it may not work since I'm using `Object.keys()` to get the keys of the object instance like this: `  const keys: string[] = Object.keys(entity);` ... This is used in the excludeKeys() function ... I included it in the example.
`